# Jmeter Issue: @ is getting replaced by %40 when trying to read data from CSV

Tags: performance, jmeter, decode, encode, jmeter-5.0

I have a scenario where I want to read the data from CSV file and use the same in a POST request. The email data contains '@' symbol.

So, when I try to hit the API using Jmeter '@' is getting replaced by '%40'. I tried below solutions but it didn't worked out:

- Uncheck 'URL Encode' checkbox
- Used __urldecode function -> ${__urldecode(abc@xyz.com)}

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: remove the `$__urldecode`

Comment: It is not working with ${USERNAME} after removing $__urldecode function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think JMeter converts anything, it should send [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) request parameters as they are, what you see in the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener is the textual representation. You can use a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to see what exactly JMeter sends:

[image]

If you switch to `HTTP` tab you should see that the username is sent with `@` symbol

[image]

If you have troubles building your HTTP requests manually consider recording just recording the request(s) using either [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/), both should produce syntactically correct [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers.